# Creating nested json

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a nested json using the sequent code. The problem is that when the system executes the line

```
jsonOnCloud = @{
                 @"server_item_id": i.ref_cloud_id,
                 @"client_item_id": extra.id_item,
                 @"extras": extras
                 };`
```

generates me the error

```
    -[__NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x110cefc0
2016-05-25 12:32:25.733 LiSchool[3145:745044] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x110cefc0'
```

this is the code

```
NSMutableArray *extras = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *jsonOnCloud = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

        NSDictionary *extraJson = @{
                                   @"action": action,
                                   @"client_id": extra.id.stringValue,
                                   @"id_repo": g.id_repository,
                                   @"page": extra.page.stringValue,
                                   @"creation_utc_client": extra.datetime_creation
                                  };

       [extras addObject:extraJson];

       jsonOnCloud = @{
                     @"server_item_id": i.ref_cloud_id,
                     @"client_item_id": extra.id_item,
                     @"extras": extras
                     };
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to do the alloc/init of `jsonOnCloud` since you set it afterwards with the short hand syntax. Could you check each values of `jsonOnCloud` `extra.id_item` for instance?

Comment: what are these: `action`, `extra`, `id`, `stingValue`, `g`, `id_repository`, `page`, `datetime_creation`, `i`, `ref_cloud_id`, `id_item` initially? and why do you init a dictionary if you directly override it two lines later? _"mess. mess is everywhere."_

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information for us to be able to help you. the code you say is crashing:

```
   jsonOnCloud = @{
                 @"server_item_id": i.ref_cloud_id,
                 @"client_item_id": extra.id_item,
                 @"extras": extras
                 };
```

Refers to objects that you don't describe.

What is `i`? And what is its ref_cloud_id property? What is `extra`, and what is its `id_item` property? It looks like `extras` is an empty mutable dictionary, so that part won't be the problem, but either `i.ref_cloud_id` or `extra.id_item` could cause a crash, depending on what those variables contain.

(To other readers: I realize this is not a complete answer, but I need the formatting of an answer in order to show code. Comments do not allow any formatting. Please forgive my mis-use of an "answer" in this case.)

Comment: I think @holex pretty much asked this very thing 15 mins before you.

Comment: @trojanfoe, his comment was terse and cryptic. I wanted to state, in clear and unambiguous terms, that we could not answer the OPs question unless he provided more information.